# After collision of two objects change the sprite and move in its direction

Tags: c#, unity, collision-detection, sprites

I've searched a lot for this question but there was no answer that could solve the problem I'm having. I'm new to unity and a very naive developer.
I'm making a game in unity using c# and it's like a bird that throws eggs in down projectile and when the egg hit the container it should destroy egg and the container sprite should change to a sprite which shows that the egg is inside the container.
It would be really helpful if someone could answer with a example code and I can implement this. Rest of the game is working fine projectile and hit. There are check points on `egg.cs` in `OnTriggerEnter2D` that `if` `target.gameObject.tag == "Container"` now here I need to change the container to another sprite I've and this should move in the direction of container.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the code which changes the sprite, but it changes the egg sprite not the container sprite.
First the declaration:

```
public Sprite changedContainer; //here I've set the sprite of Changed Container
private SpriteRenderer spriteRend;
```

Then in the start method:

```
spriteRend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
```

and finally my onCollision Trigger method: (Read the comment in my code)

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target)
    {
        if (target.gameObject.tag == "Container") //if the egg collide with container
        {
            transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = changedContainer; <br //which it did successfully
            Instantiate(changedContainer, target.gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity); //as it is mentioned that target.gameobject.transform.position but it still takes the egg projectile
        }
}
```

So how to change the spite of container? I think I'm in the wrong class I should be doing this in the container class. But it is the projectile of egg that collides not the container that collides with egg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if egg.cs is attached to the egg, then writing:

```
transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = changedContainer;
```

will change the egg component, so maybe use

```
target.gameObject.transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = changedContainer;
```

Comment: This `transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = changedContainer;` worked just perfectly fine for me and it changed the container not the egg. I used it inside `OnTriggerEnter2D` where the container is respawning.

Comment: Sry maybe try to let me see more code, so at the end you have 2 changedContainer? you want the egg to be destroyed? I don't understand also why you use 'Istantiate()' if you want only to change the sprite.